# set images in imageview to make it look like a progressbar

Tags: android, imageview

im trying to make an arc progress (just like the c cleaner app) using 11 images to represent progress. i have the images prepared However, i want to set each image in my imageview according to the percentage. for instance,

if

10% - img1

else if

20% - img2

else if

30% - img3

and so on

```
public static int getWifiStrengthPercentage(Context context) {
    try {
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        int rssi = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getRssi();
        int level = WifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(rssi, 10);
        int percentage = (int) ((level / 10.0) * 100);
        tv.setText(percentage + " %");
        return percentage;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Consule this https://github.com/Todd-Davies/ProgressWheel library. It will help

Comment: i dont want to use a library do to some requirement.

Comment: Whats the problem here? if you want to set the different image based on the percentage, I dont see any issue here, am I missing anything? Do you need to animate it?

Comment: dude how do i detect the different percentages and set images according to it???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do this :

```
if(percentage == 10)
{
img.setImageResource(R.drawable.imgPercentage10); 
}
else if(percentage == 20)
{
img.setImageResource(R.drawable.imgPercentage20);
}
.
.
```

// here imgPercentage10,imgPercentage20  are images in your drawable folder
and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Try do it in AsyncTask:

```
public class DoStuffAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

    ImageView progImg;

    public DoStuffAsyncTask(ImageView progImg) {
        this.progImg = progImg;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        // Do Stuff
        ...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        if (10%) {
            progImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.img1)
            // Set whatever
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always set the imageResource to the imageview dynamically.

```
  ImageView imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgView);
  switch(getWifiStrengthPercentage(this)) {
      case 10:
      imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.img1);
      break;
      case 20:
      imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.img2);
      default:
      .....
    }
```